# Prove true or false: for all rational numbers $x$, there exist unique integers $a$ and $b$ such that $x = a/b$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation

I must prove whether this is true or false. I think that it is false because when $b=0$, it does not hold true.
Suppose $x=a/b$. Let $x\in A$ and let $x\in B$. suppose $B=0$. Then for $x=a/0$, the answer is undefined. therefore, $x=a/b$ is not true.
I'm not sure if this is at all correct

Comment: Note that $\frac{a}{b}=\frac{ka}{kb}$ for all $k\neq0$.

Answer (score 1):

You're thinking about it the wrong way.  It starts with "for all rational numbers $x$" so if you want to contradict it, pick a rational number $x$.  Say $x = \frac{1}{2}$.  There are integers $a = 1$, $b = 2$, such that $x = \frac{a}{b}$.  But are they unique?  In other words, is that the only pair of integers that satisfies the same equality?

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, the definition of *rational number* from wiki is that, *a rational number is any number that can be expressed as the quotient or fraction $p/q$ of two integers, a numerator p and a non-zero denominator $q$*. So the key point is that if $p-q$ pair is unique.

1. if $a=0$: for $a=1/2$, and $a = 2/4 = 3/6 = ... = (1*k)/(2*k)$
2. if $a \neq0$: for $a=0/k$, $k$ can be any integer except 0.